# 404 while trying to configure androidLint plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I'm getting a problem with the Lint configuration on Jenkins. I was able to configure others static analysis but with the Lint I'm getting the error bellow:

> HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing
>   /job/VDA_NIGHLTY_BUILD/androidLint/configureDefaults. Reason:
>       Not Found

What I'm trying to do:

[image]

I have no idea about what is going on. 
I also tried to reinstall the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This due to version incompatibility between the Android Lint Plugin and the dependent Static Analysis Utilities (analysis-core) plugin. Downgrade the Static Analysis Utilities plugin to 1.79. You can find the old version here http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/analysis-core/

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long to anwser you. You where right! Thanks!